# how to create folder and add file in azure web app using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to do a simple task of creating a folder in an azure web app and add a file in it. Here is what I've achieved so far and need some help with the right commands

```
Add-AzureAccount 
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Demo' 
$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name 'test--app' -ResourceGroupName 'TEST-POC-AUTOMATION'

$webApp.<CANT FIGURE OUT WHICH COMMAND>

$root = 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT'
if (!(Test-Path $root)) 
{
md $root
}
```

I am trying to wonder if this is possible or i've to use KUDU API to achieve this. Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Kudu API to do this, check this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API).

```
PUT /api/vfs/{path}/
Creates a directory at path. The path can be nested, e.g. `folder1/folder2`.
```

If you want to use Power Shell to call the API, you could check this [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabeshapiro/2017/01/01/samples-for-using-the-azure-app-service-kudu-rest-api-to-programmatically-manage-files-in-your-site/).